# regex - Match # part of the url on the server

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to write a regex to match parts of urls and use a SEO redirection wordpress plugin to create a 301 redirect on the matching results.

if, for example, I write these URLs:

```
https://www.test.com/my-site
https://www.test.com/my-site/
```

I want to be redirect to:

```
https://www.test.com/your-site/
```

but if the urls are followed by an hash (#) like the one below:

```
https://www.test.com/my-site/#/..
```

Do not redirect.

I have played around for a bit with regExr and this is as far as I could get:

[regexr.com/3scpb](http://regexr.com/3scpb)

But when try to implement it inside the plugin the redirect doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong here?
Is it better to do it straight inside the .htaccess file?
would it be better and more robust/reliable that way?

Thanks

Comment: Try `(?<=.com\/)([\w-]+\/?$)` and replace with `your-site\/` [here](https://regex101.com/r/BWCP8S/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is never sent by the browser.

The hash is used internally by the browser to see which fragment of the document is focused on. This is called [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This means your server will never see the # coming up. You cannot prevent this behavior.